# How can I use the same name for two or more different variables in a single C# function?

Tags: c#, variables, scope, identifier

How do I delete a variable that is once declared and defined?

For example, in C++ I would do:

```
int x;

..

delete x;
```

How can I do it in C#?

(i need to do something like this:

```
switch (something)
{
case 1:
int Number;
break;

case 2:
float Number;
break;
}
```

But I can't do it, because Number is already taken by case 1... And I want the same name, so I want to delete int Number before float Number is declared, so compilator won't shout at me. ;p

Comment: `delete x;` in C++ doesn't do what I think you think it does...

Comment: Simple; you don't. Just name your variables differently. As @BenVoigt said, `delete` in C++ doesn't do this either. And please tell me you aren't deleting your ints in C++, thats just weird.

Comment: You wouldn't do that in C++.

Comment: C# does it's own garbage collection on native types.  If you are dealing with an object that is not native, they usually come with a Dispose() function which does the "deleting".  In your case, you probably don't need it

Comment: @juanchopanza Agreeeed!

Comment: "Too Broad"?  Or is that being used as a catch-all for "It's not worthy"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the scopes non-overlapping using braces:

```
switch (something)
{
  case 1: {
    int Number;
  }
  break;

  case 2: {
    float Number;
  }
  break;
}
```

Going out of scope is the only way a variable name is "deleted" in the sense you are talking about.  Notably and unlike some other languages, C# doesn't allow hiding local variables with other variables in more limited scopes -- the scopes have to be non-overlapping (and in C#, that means from the opening brace, not simply the point of declaration!).  What I mean is that this code, which is legal in C and C++ (not sure about Java) will cause a compiler error in C#:

```
int Number;
{
    float Number;
}
```

Comment: I've thinked about it at the beginning of the problem, and Visual Studio keeps crying. :/


//edit:

Oh wait, I added bracers to case 1, but not to case 2, that's the problem... :P
Thanks.